# How do Static Loop-Transformations Work

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics, implicit-function

Loop-Transformations (input feedforward or output feedback) can be used for passivity analysis, also in the case when considering a static (memoryless) nonlinearity. This is described for example in Nonlinear Systems (Khalil, page 267). Let

$$
y_s = f(u) \tag{1}
$$

be such a nonlinearity (for example, $f$ can be a saturation function). I understand the input feedforward case, which is

$$
y_s = f(u) - k_1 u \tag{2}
$$

But for output feedback, the equation gets

$$
y_s = f(u + k_2 y_s) \tag{3}
$$

So the problem is now that $(3)$ isn't an explicit equation anymore for $y_f$. So, how could I compute $y_s$ now, for example in a simulation? Do I have to provide an initial condition for $y_s$? If yes, which value should I choose?

**Question**: How to deal in general with loop transformations that lead to implicit equations that can't be isolated?

Comment: When you apply feedback to a memoryless function, you implicitly construct a new memoryless function, given by a solution of (3). You can see it as an algebraic loop. In the general case, I do not see any reason why there should be a closed-form solution.

Comment: However, since you are reading Khalil's book, I would like to give you a short spoiler. These input/output passivity modifications are not typically used for real design, i.e. they are not (typically) implemented in practice. They are rather used for proofs and analysis.

Comment: @Arastas Yes, the modification is not really implemented, but I meant for simulation. So I basically want to implement it in simulation only to check if the modification is correct (because then it should have the same output like the original).

Comment: To use it in simulations, your software has to solve (3) with respect to $y$ given the input $u$.

Comment: @Arastas But to solve $(3)$, I have to provide an initial condition for the fixpoint iteration, right? My question is now how to choose that in general? How can I guarantee that the initial condition makes the solver converge to the "correct" solution that represents the loop transformed memoryless nonlinearity? At the end, I want to be sure I am simulating "the right" thing.

Comment: I am not sure if there exist some general recommendations for an arbitrary $f$. However, this question is now about the convergence of fixpoint iterations and implementation in certain simulation software; not about Control Theory anymore. My competence is over. :)